# Ubuntu Unity + headless desktop sharing

Tags: vnc, ubuntu-16.04, chrome-remote-desktop

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 on the Google Compute Engine and I want to install Unity 7.4 desktop over it and connect to it with Google Remote Desktop.

It is my development machine (headless desktop), not a standalone server which needs to be minimal. As I work on the go, I am used to work remotely in the cloud. There is no problem with hardware as I can increase the RAM, CPU or HDD as needed.

1. After I install ubuntu-desktop package I am not able to connect SSH port 22 to my compute engine instance anymore and I lost control completely and have to recreate new instance.
2. There is no headless Google Remote Desktop installer, so basically I have to install temporary VNC to install Chrome, then configure the Chrome RDP headless service to run on system startup, delete the temporary VNC connection and after that I should be able to connect there anytime with my Chrome client on the go.

I have following questions:

- Is Unity able to work with VNC? I have found only tutorials for XFCE and similar lightweight desktops.
- Is Unity able to work with Google RDP?
- What about performance? There is no 3D graphics card in Google Cloud
- I have LTE on the go, so network should be no problem.
- if impossible to run Unity remotely, which lightweight desktop is closest to it? (I am quite a Mac fan)

Comment: Have a look at this answer from askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795703/chrome-remote-desktop-access-to-headless-ubuntu-server-16-04-machine